# Retrieving shared permissions using google doc api

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, google-docs-api

Im trying to access the following docs using java:

1. doc is only accessible from people within the domain that have the link
2. doc is only accessible from people outside the domain that have the link

These are all sharable settings within google docs but i cant seen to figure out the api call to retrieve them.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: You should clarify in your question that you (seemingly) want to make this request from an App Engine app, and that you are using GWT. My answer makes this request from the server, and doesn't depend on your app using GWT.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you will need to access the [Documents List API](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html), specifically, you will need to [receive the ACL](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#ACLRetrieve) of the resource in question, and check the `<gAcl:scope>` element of the `<entry>` elements for one that has the `type='domain'` in question.

To do this in Java, you can use the [Google API Java client library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/). See [this sample](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/docs-v3-atom-oauth-sample/instructions.html?r=default) for an example of how to make a request to the Documents List API.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jason.  I have done this for another report but doesn't this return all docs shared to the entire domain and not just the docs shared to the user within the domain with the link to the doc? So basically you have two types:

Comment: I'm not aware of a setting in Docs that allows access from any domain *outside* of a domain, just one *within* a domain. But I admit I'm not an expert on the Docs List API. You may get more luck asking in the forum: http://code.google.com/apis/documents/forum.html

Comment: I appreciate your replies.  Basically there is a share type to allow access in 4 flavors.  1 to an entire domain, 2 to a user within the domain but has access to the link, 3 to the public, 4 to the public but only public users with the link... i may be confused on this but if you go to share a google doc these are the options listed there.